# can I implement customized table cell which can be suitable for different column types in tableview Javafx

Tags: tableview, javafx-8

I have a tableview which has about 18 columns with different data types, Can I define a customized table cell that can handle all these data types So I can set the cell factory for all these columns to this customized table cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only displaying text, you can do something like this:

```
public class SimpleTextCell<S,T> extends TableCell<S ,T> {

    private final Function<T,String> textExtractor ;

    public SimpleTextCell(Function<T, String> textExtractor) {
        this.textExtractor = textExtractor ;
    }

    public SimpleTextCell() {
        this(T::toString);
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        setText(empty ? null : textExtractor.apply(item));
    }
}
```

(and you can add more functionality to the `updateItem(...)` method as you need).

Now you can do things like

```
TableColumn<Item, String> someStringColumn = new TableColumn<>();
someStringColumn.setCellFactory(tc -> new SimpleTextCell<>());

TableColumn<Item, Double> someDoubleColumn = new TableColumn<>();
someDoubleColumn.setCellFactory(tc -> 
    new SimpleTextCell<>(d -> String.format("%.3f", d.doubleValue())));
```

or, if it's enough to use the default behavior for each one,

```
TableColumn<Item, String> someStringColumn = new TableColumn<>();
TableColumn<Item, Double> someDoubleColumn = new TableColumn<>();

TableView<Item> table = new TableView<>();
table.getColumns().add(someStringColumn);
table.getColumns().add(someDoubleColumn);

table.getColumns().forEach(col -> col.setCellFactory(tc -> new SimpleTextCell<>()));
```

Comment: Thanx @James_D, but how can I detect the type of the second parameter at run time, I want to write a for loop for all columns in the table view and assign the them the same TableCell, TableColumn<Item, String> someStringColumn = new TableColumn<>();
someStringColumn.setCellFactory(tc -> new SimpleTextCell<Item, String>()); How can I detect that I'm using String DataType inside the updateItem method

Comment: You can't dynamically check the parametrized type of the table column at runtime due to type erasure. It's not really clear what you want to do here: if you want different behavior for different table column types, then you are not really using the same table cell implementation at all. (You could, of course, just do `instanceof` tests inside the `updateItem()` method, but it would be pretty ugly.) Since you presumably know the table column type when you create the column, why not register the cell factory then?

Comment: Also see update, which maybe gives you a bit more flexibility.